# Cannot get lock when running `sudo apt-get update`

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I issue `sudo apt-get update` on the command line I get the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: m running on advanced -unbuntu linux

Comment: can any one help me

Answer (score 2):

This message means that something else is currently using apt-get. Are you installing upgrades from the Ubuntu software center or otherwise installing another program? If so, try waiting until it's finished then try again.